# Waiting for server response takes a very long time

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax

This is the framework i used for my application:

1. Frontend: ReactJS
2. Backend: PHP (hosted on the server)

So, the problem is when I am running my ReactJS on `localhost` with `npm start`, the Ajax request only takes around `500ms`

But when I hosted ReactJS and called the request, it takes around `2.51 seconds` shown in the image below:

[image]

Using the same request, I tested out on `postman`, it takes also around `500ms` which is shown in the image below:

[image]

Anyone know what can I try to do to find where the time is wasted at? Why the waiting for server response is different?

Here is the Ajax request written in the ReactJS for the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: MY_URL,
  dataType: "json",
  data: MY_DATA,
  success: function (data) {
      // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: We need more context. Is this Postman result of localhost or the backend code hosted on a server?

Comment: The backend code hosted on the server too

Comment: So this Postman result is from the server?

Comment: yup, result is from the server

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share the backend API URL?

Comment: sorry, I can't do that, it is my company's data :c.
Is there any recommendation for me to do myself. Like how to see where the problem is

Comment: If the avg. response time is around 500 ms for the backend API, issue might be with your frontend then, although code snippets can provide more insight.

Comment: You've double checked Postman is referencing the remote API and not the local one? It's an easy mistake to make and the response times are the same.

Another thing to check would be that you haven't enabled throttling in the browers developer tools (In Chrome it's next to the Disable cache option on the network tab)

There can be other causes of significantly slow connections in browser performance (Extensions for AV, proxy usage) but 2 seconds is an extreme difference.

Comment: Added the ajax code, but I am very curious why on localhost, the ajax is fast, but when I deploy it to the server, it becomes slow... both using the same code... but differnt speed

Comment: Yes i checked the postman is reference to the remote API. And I didnt enable throttling in the browser dev tools. Also dont have extension for AV, proxy usage.